# How to fix the Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am currently making a project using Angular with Node JS, when I use the command `node index.js` in the terminal, It says server is running on port 3000, but yet when I check the localhost:3000 it then say the error Error: `ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\Licensed User\PrulifeUK_Southern_Jade\dist\index.html'` Even though the index.html is within the file `dist` folder.  I don't really know what is this all about.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7XyX.png)
the image shows that the index.html is present within the `dist` folder.
This is the code within the index.js:

```
// index.js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b4Fu.png): These are my folders.

Chat GPT instructed me to create a server.js file with the code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Serve static files from the 'dist' directory
app.use(express.static('dist'));

// Other routes and server logic

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

but it still does not work.

Comment: index.html seems to be in a folder `dist\southern-j...` not directly in `dist`

Comment: Try this: `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'))`.